# dataTables Column Filtering Plugin with Select Tags

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables v1.92 along with the column filtering plugin v1.5.0.

#### THE PROBLEM

I need to create drodowns for individual column filtering whose markup will be

```
<option value="1">Abc</option>
<option value="2">Def</option>
<option value="3">Ghi</option>
```

This is because the values coming from the database are `1, 2, or 3`. The label displayed to the user is either `Abc, Def, or Ghi`

Using the column filtering plugin, I'm able to create a dropdown for a column using

```
.columnFilter({
    aoColumns: [ type : 'select', values:['1', '2', '3']
               ]
         });
```

The problem is that the markup of that dropdown turns out to be

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

So the user is shown `1, 2, 3` as the drop down labels instead of `Abc, Def, Ghi`

#### WHAT I TRIED

I tried to hardcode the dropdown in the `<tfoot>` section of the datatable, but then

```
.columnFilter({
    aoColumns: [ type : 'select', values:['1', '2', '3']
                   ]
             });
```

overwrites the hardcoded dropdown. I even tried passing `null` as the parameter for `aoColumns` but that didn't work too as it simply removed the hardcoded dropdown.

So is there a way that I can create the dropdown in which the `value` attribute will hold a numerical value whereas the label between `<option>` and `</option>` will be text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have solved this yet but looking at the dataTables plugin site I can't see a way around doing what you have asked.

But for a workaround you can create the `<select>` menu before hand and then using the `fnFilter` callback to update your column with a specific vale.

E.g

```
<select>
   <option value="1">ABC</option>
   <option value="2">DEF</option>
   <option value="3">GHI</option>
</select>
```

-

```
$('select').change(function(){
    yourTable.fnFilter($(this).val(),colNum);
    // With colNum being the targeted column.  
});
```

The above will then filter the table by the value of your `<option>` tags, e.g. `1`. But if you're looking at filtering by the ABC enclosed in the `<option>` tag.

```
$('select').change(function(){
   yourTable.fnFilter($('select option:selected').text(),colNum); 
});
```

Hope this was of some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js`, then the following approach will work for you:

instead of writing:

```
type : 'select', values:['1', '2', '3']
```

write this:

```
"type": "select", values: [{ label: "ABC", value: "1" }, { label: "DEF", value: "2" }]
```