# Datatables tags search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I've been trying to get tags working with Jquery Datatables for about 1 week now with no luck! 
I've gone through stackoverflow and have not found the help i'm looking for.

This post here was insightful:

[dataTables Column Filtering Plugin with Select Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039501/datatables-column-filtering-plugin-with-select-tags)

I am using jquery.tag-editor to create the tags and using this code I can successfully create tags inside the global search box:

```
      $('div.dataTables_filter input').tagEditor();
```

my issue is that the tags are not filtering the Datatable as expected, I know that the table needs to be redrawn but from what I can see the tagEditor creates 3 div's inside a ul inside the searchbox:

```
    <li><div class="tag-editor-spacer"></div>
    <div class="tag-editor-tag">january</div>
    <div class="tag-editor-delete"><i></i></div></li>
```

with the middle div tag-editor-tag containing the string I want to use to filter the datatable. On change it should redraw the table using the value inside the tag-editor-tag div.
I think this is close as I have seen to what I want it to do but have no idea how to ignore the divs and get the middle value.

```
    $('div.dataTables_filter input').change(function(){
    table.fnFilter($('.....').text()); 
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Doing some more reading I believe I can use inner.HTML somehow to parse the information in the div and exclude the <li> tags too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not add the tag-editor plugin to the default search input of DataTables.
Simply create your own search field. This can easily be done by taking the following steps.

1. Take a look at the `dom` option of dataTables.

> [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)
>
> Define the table control elements to appear on the page and in what order.

Using the `dom` option you can hide the default search input field adding a custom `div` element instead.

---

2. Take a look at the events being fired during the initialisation of dataTables.

> [init](https://datatables.net/reference/event/init)
>
> Initialisation complete event - fired when DataTables has been fully initialised and data loaded.
>
> [preInit](https://datatables.net/reference/event/preInit)
>
> Initialisation started event - triggered immediately before data load.

Use the `preInit` event to append a search input-field or textarea to the custom div element that was created using the `dom` option.

Use the `init` event to hook up the tag-editor plugin to the appended search input field.

---

3. Make use of the dataTables `search` API method to do the search, whenever the `change` event on the tag-editor search field has been triggered.

> [search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search())
>
> Search for data in the table.

Here is an example using a static HTML table.

```js
var $tagsLabel = $("<lable>")
var $tagsInput = $("<textarea>");

$table = $("#example")
  .on("preInit.dt", function( e, settings) {
  $tagsLabel.append($tagsInput)
  $('.dataTables_tags').append($tagsLabel)
})
  .on("init.dt", function( e, settings ) {
  $tagsInput.tagEditor({
    delimiter: ', ',
    placeholder: 'Enter tags ...',
    onChange: function(field, editor, tags) {
      if ( tags.length ) {
        if( tags.length > 1 ) {
          $table.search(tags.join('|'), true, false).draw();
        } else {
          $table.search( tags[0] ).draw();
        }
      }
      else {
        $table.search('').draw(true);
      }
    },
  });
})
  .DataTable({
  "dom": '<l<"dataTables_tags"><t>ip>'
});
```

```css
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_tags {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/caret/1.0.0/jquery.caret.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <thead> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Position</th> <th>Office</th> <th>Age</th> <th>Start date</th> <th>Salary</th> </tr></thead> <tfoot> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Position</th> <th>Office</th> <th>Age</th> <th>Start date</th> <th>Salary</th> </tr></tfoot> <tbody> <tr> <td>Tiger Nixon</td><td>System Architect</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>61</td><td>2011/04/25</td><td>$320,800</td></tr><tr> <td>Garrett Winters</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>63</td><td>2011/07/25</td><td>$170,750</td></tr><tr> <td>Ashton Cox</td><td>Junior Technical Author</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>66</td><td>2009/01/12</td><td>$86,000</td></tr><tr> <td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Senior Javascript Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2012/03/29</td><td>$433,060</td></tr><tr> <td>Airi Satou</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>33</td><td>2008/11/28</td><td>$162,700</td></tr><tr> <td>Brielle Williamson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>New York</td><td>61</td><td>2012/12/02</td><td>$372,000</td></tr><tr> <td>Herrod Chandler</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>59</td><td>2012/08/06</td><td>$137,500</td></tr><tr> <td>Rhona Davidson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>55</td><td>2010/10/14</td><td>$327,900</td></tr><tr> <td>Colleen Hurst</td><td>Javascript Developer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>39</td><td>2009/09/15</td><td>$205,500</td></tr><tr> <td>Sonya Frost</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>23</td><td>2008/12/13</td><td>$103,600</td></tr><tr> <td>Jena Gaines</td><td>Office Manager</td><td>London</td><td>30</td><td>2008/12/19</td><td>$90,560</td></tr><tr> <td>Quinn Flynn</td><td>Support Lead</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2013/03/03</td><td>$342,000</td></tr><tr> <td>Charde Marshall</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>36</td><td>2008/10/16</td><td>$470,600</td></tr><tr> <td>Haley Kennedy</td><td>Senior Marketing Designer</td><td>London</td><td>43</td><td>2012/12/18</td><td>$313,500</td></tr><tr> <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>London</td><td>19</td><td>2010/03/17</td><td>$385,750</td></tr><tr> <td>Michael Silva</td><td>Marketing Designer</td><td>London</td><td>66</td><td>2012/11/27</td><td>$198,500</td></tr><tr> <td>Paul Byrd</td><td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td><td>New York</td><td>64</td><td>2010/06/09</td><td>$725,000</td></tr><tr> <td>Gloria Little</td><td>Systems Administrator</td><td>New York</td><td>59</td><td>2009/04/10</td><td>$237,500</td></tr><tr> <td>Bradley Greer</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>41</td><td>2012/10/13</td><td>$132,000</td></tr><tr> <td>Dai Rios</td><td>Personnel Lead</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>35</td><td>2012/09/26</td><td>$217,500</td></tr><tr> <td>Jenette Caldwell</td><td>Development Lead</td><td>New York</td><td>30</td><td>2011/09/03</td><td>$345,000</td></tr><tr> <td>Yuri Berry</td><td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td><td>New York</td><td>40</td><td>2009/06/25</td><td>$675,000</td></tr><tr> <td>Caesar Vance</td><td>Pre-Sales Support</td><td>New York</td><td>21</td><td>2011/12/12</td><td>$106,450</td></tr><tr> <td>Doris Wilder</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>Sidney</td><td>23</td><td>2010/09/20</td><td>$85,600</td></tr><tr> <td>Angelica Ramos</td><td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td><td>London</td><td>47</td><td>2009/10/09</td><td>$1,200,000</td></tr></tbody> </table>
```