# How to make Datatable to search by tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatable

I want to make a search that will search by tags within the datatable values just like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44110669/12029052) did, but my way of creating datatable is quite different. I used jquery Ajax to fill the table. I want the tags to be focused on `customerName` ie. (data[2]).

```
$(function(){
    showDataTable();
});

function showDataTable() {
    reportsDataTable = $('#reportsDataTable').DataTable({
        emptyTable      : 'No record of Company found',
        lengthChange    : true,
        processing      : true,
        responsive      :true,
        scrollX:        true,
        ajax : {
            'url'   : '/reports/findAll',
            'type'  : 'POST'
        },
        columns : [
            {'data' : 'issueDate'},
            {'data' : 'values'},
            {'data' : 'customerName'}
        ],
        searching   : true,
        buttons : ['excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'copy'],
       scrollCollapse: true
    });
}
```

I tried to implement the same way as that guy did but the search field gets disappear. Is there any way to implement it.

Please help!!..

Comment: have you tried using `GET` instead of `POST` method in your ajax call?

Comment: @Pau i'm getting the data, the problem is I want to search the customer values by making tags

Comment: Is it when you type customerName inside the search box, it will show all customers?

Comment: I tried to reimplement this one, and it worked.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106475/datatables-tags-search/44110669#44110669. I believe your table already rendered the data you need. I think You might need to refactor/recheck some codes.

Comment: @Pau Okay I'll consider your thoughts on this..thankyou very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One rule of thumb I follow while working on frontend technologies like javascript, jquery is to check and then double-check script tags/cdn links
I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106475/datatables-tags-search/44110669#44110669) might help you solve your problem.